# Метод который возвращает русское название дня недели с английского в одну строку

Tags: java

Задача в том чтобы метод getRusName() возвращал русское название дня недели. Метод должен быть сделан в одну строку. Единственное что я нашел более менее подходящее это пробовать через SimpleDateFormat, но как не пытался так и не понял можно ли с помощью этого класса решить в одну строку данных метод. У кого какие идеи есть?

Дополнительно: регистр вывода не важен

```
public enum Day {
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY;

    public String getRusName() {
        switch (this) {
            case MONDAY -> {
                return "Понедельник";
            }
            case TUESDAY -> {
                return "Вторник";
            }
            case WEDNESDAY -> {
                return "Среда";
            }
            case THURSDAY -> {
                return "Четверг";
            }
            case FRIDAY -> {
                return "Пятница";
            }
            case SATURDAY -> {
                return "Суббота";
            }
            case SUNDAY -> {
                return "Воскресенье";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3791277/4908529  С небольшой доработкой - легко может лечь в одну строку

Comment: А есть ли ограничение, что должен быть один лишь только метод? Потому что можно ведь просто хранить строку-псевдоним (условно `alias`), сделать конструктор, принимающий один параметр - эту самую строку. И при перечислении для каждого члена `enum`-а просто её передавать. То есть, вот так: `MONDAY("Понедельник"), TUESDAY("Вторник"), ...`. А метод `getRusName()` просто будет делать `return alias;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В любом случае придётся прописывать переводы, и как по мне это самый короткий вариант:

```java
public enum Day {
    MONDAY("Понедельник"),
    TUESDAY("Вторник"),
    WEDNESDAY("Среда"),
    THURSDAY("Четверг"),
    FRIDAY("Пятница"),
    SATURDAY("Суббота"),
    SUNDAY("Воскресенье");
    
    String russian;
    Day(String rus) { russian = rus; }
    public String getRusName() { return russian; }
}
```

Использование:

```java
Day day = Day.MONDAY;
System.out.println(day.getRusName())
```

Comment: Каким образом это использование? Если у меня на входе "вторник", то ``System.out.println(Day.MONDAY.russian)`` даст неверный результат

Comment: @Эникейщик Очевидно, что вместо Day.MONDAY может быть переменная типа `Day`. Но если хотите могу уточнить это в ответе

Comment: Хорошее решение, но требования такие: сигнатура метода getRusName() и метод getRusName возвращает String. То есть конструкция не подходит

Comment: Это понятно. Но вопрос был как английское название дня недели перевести в русское. Вам дали в метод "вторник" или "четверг", вы должны вывести соответственно "Tuesday" или "Thursday". А просто вывести "Понедельник" можно и без дополнительных переменных.

Comment: @Эникейщик Уже отредактировал вопрос) Спасибо за замечание

Comment: @Floppy Вы можете просто сделать метод, который возвращает приватное поле. Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей увидел, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Стандартный способ для получения названий дней недели из заданной локали -- метод [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName(TextStyle style, Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-):

```java
DayOfWeek dow = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek();

Locale ru = new Locale("ru", "RU");

System.out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, ru));  // вторник
System.out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, ru)); // вт
```

Для русской локали названия дней недели по умолчанию пишутся со строчной буквы.

Также существует класс [`DateFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html), в котором кроме чтения названий дней недели `getWeekdays()` / `getShortWeekdays()` при желании можно установить новые значения для написания дней недели.